# Are indirect links to own blog within code blocks considered spam?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

I recently stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53339977/8411406) which answers a question from the same user.

The code block in this answer contains links to presumably the author's GitHub page, website and YouTube channel (not disclosed affiliation).

Excerpt from the answer in question:

```
// Project name: id0000131-convert-index-entries-into-Word-or-Google-Doc-comments
// Github: Adobe Indesign Script examples: https://github.com/firedevelop/id0000013-Adobe-InDesign-Scripts-Examples
// Github of this project: id0000131-convert-adobe-indesign-index-into-Word-or-Google-Doc-comments
// YouTube Playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdbMQ5CoohPqK8ekjthm2fNoGMLwYeFf
// Blog: https://www.firedevelop.com/2018/11/id0000131-convert-index-entries-into.html
// Script Author:
// Peter Kahrel -- www.kahrel.plus.com
// http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/index-to-text.jsx
// http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/index_to_text.html
```

- The code however seems to somewhat solve the question
- It is not a direct link (you can't click on it)
- They linked the site where they got the code from (last 2 links)
- They asked the question, but then took some time before writing the answer, so it doesn't look like a spam seed (?)

Is this considered to be spam and should I flag it as such?

Comment: Also watch out for links encoded as rebuses hidden in the first letters of each sentence.

Comment: I don't see an issue as long as the answer stands by itself and the links are at least relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: How do you know the gender of that user?

Comment: @PeterMortensen i don't, what would be the appropriate way to address a user with unknown gender? (sorry, English is not my primary language)

Comment: @Turtlefight a Singular They seems to be the current gender neutral trend.  I've edited to demonstrate, hope you don't mind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posts with links in code blocks are usually OK (especially if they disclose affiliation). The only case where this may not be true is if there are multiple related links (i.e. by the same person/company) that do not disclose affiliation, in which case they are not.

However, this specific case is *definitely* spam.

The answer and the question are both by the same user, which is called a "spam seed". Flag both.

The first five links in code block are to FireDevelop-related sites and the code seems to come from another site (which might count as plagiarism).

The answer doesn't answer the question, from what I can tell. It also may be in the wrong language (JavaScript as opposed to Google Apps Script).

I would even consider flagging this post for moderator attention and note that the user is creating "spam seeds" and should probably be deleted or banned.

Comment: Not my vote... but I don't see any direct evidence of spam in this case... At very least it looks like author had a question, worked on it and then posted answer to blog and SO in couple days (or less likely copy-pasted someone else solution with proper attribution)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Note the username, the *multiple links* to firedevelop-related resources they include in the answer, and the low-quality question.

Comment: Not my vote either - the first 5 links in code block are to sites from the user & the code seems to come from another site, presumably not affiliated with the user (the following 3 links)

Comment: @Turtlefight Thanks. Incorporated.